How to find what is preventing a question from being submitted?
Occasionally I see on the top right "Your question couldn't be submitted" followed by a text that does not really help me. "Resolve 1 issue before posting". There is no hint what the issue could be - the reason is not clarified. For instance what is wrong in the following?

How do I find easily what is preventing a question from being asked?
Wouldn't it be helpful to show a list of all the sections that prevent the question from being asked instead of a mere "Resolve 1 issue..."?

The 'Tags' section has a red star, ... and looks empty...? // (Several typos btw in your quotes...)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58009668/1426539

Please share the screenshot of the full page, not cut off above the tags input box.

@chivracq: don´t see a red star unfortunately. they're all black to me.

Is there a way to suggest improvements to the UI-designers of this site? The black/dark-red contrast is too little for about 5% of your audience.

@TylerH too late I had to give up on this for me unsurmountable challange.

I don't think the contrast or color choice is relevant. What's relevant is that there is a star at all. The color is presumably the same for any viewer between instances where it appears and at the top right above the form where the key says `Required Fields*". If anything, that key needs to be more prominent. Of course, this all assumes the issue is in fact that you have a required field somewhere that isn't filled out.

In the meantime, the question can't be reproduced, and if you're not interested in trying to make it contain all the information necessary, we can only vote to close this as not reproducible.

Nah, I disagree that the star needs a different colour. The fact that the star is there is enough of a signal that the field is required. And even if you miss that, the form gives plenty of feedback should you try to submit it (see my answer).

I suggest we agree to disagree on this. And this userinterface could so easily be improved.

Well, then suggest improvements. "This is bad" isn't helpful.

The contents of your screenshot don't seem to be the problem.
As other users have suggested, it seems like you might've missed entering some tags.
Now, the red star isn't the only hint you'd get, at the fact that tags are required.
If your tag input is actually empty, this is what you see if you try to submit the question:

Main:


That's more than enough to signal you missed something.

That probably is a matter of opinion and I was not able to see that at one glance, certainly with a larger question with lots of additional help. FR: Why not add a clicking list to all sections that need update (instead of micro printing a message using obscure colors etc.)

The textbox turned red, a red exclamation mark was added and a red error message was added. What more do you want?

I also don't know what that edit was about? It didn't change my answer...
